# MediaSession is leaking in audio app with LeakCanary crash

Tags: android, leakcanary, android-mediasession

I found a weird leak in my audio application where the audio `Service` gets leaked if we dismiss the application from the app overview screen (square button or swipe up depending on device).  After dismissing the application, re-opening this same applicaiton rapidly will bring about the same session we just attempted to close, half teared down and leaking the audio `Service` in the form of a `AudioPlayerService`.
Here's the leak report as per LeakCanary:

```
2021-11-30 17:43:12.696 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ​
2021-11-30 17:43:12.696 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ====================================
2021-11-30 17:43:12.696 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
2021-11-30 17:43:12.696 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ====================================
2021-11-30 17:43:12.696 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: 1 APPLICATION LEAKS
2021-11-30 17:43:12.696 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
2021-11-30 17:43:12.696 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.
2021-11-30 17:43:12.696 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: 9966 bytes retained by leaking objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: Signature: c66398a2a91f6817ce902cdec3748a8398a58154
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ┬───
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │ GC Root: Input or output parameters in native code
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ okio.AsyncTimeout class
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (PathClassLoader↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ static AsyncTimeout.$class$classLoader
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ dalvik.system.PathClassLoader instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (AppModuleKt↓ is not leaking and A ClassLoader is never leaking)
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ ClassLoader.runtimeInternalObjects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ java.lang.Object[] array
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (AppModuleKt↓ is not leaking)
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ Object[].[2671]
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ com.mixhalo.client.di.AppModuleKt class
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ static AppModuleKt.AppModule
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │                         ~~~~~~~~~
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ org.koin.core.module.Module instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 118 B in 4 objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ Module.definitions
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │             ~~~~~~~~~~~
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ java.util.ArrayList instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 80 B in 2 objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ ArrayList.elementData
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │                ~~~~~~~~~~~
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ java.lang.Object[] array
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 60 B in 1 objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ Object[].[2]
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │               ~~~
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ org.koin.core.definition.BeanDefinition instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 15.2 kB in 166 objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ BeanDefinition.instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │                     ~~~~~~~~
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ org.koin.core.instance.SingleDefinitionInstance instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 15.1 kB in 161 objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ SingleDefinitionInstance.value
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │                               ~~~~~
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ com.mixhalo.client.repositories.MediaControllerRepository instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 15.1 kB in 160 objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ MediaControllerRepository.controllerChannel
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ConflatedBroadcastChannel instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 15.1 kB in 159 objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ ConflatedBroadcastChannel._state
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │                                ~~~~~~
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ConflatedBroadcastChannel$State instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 15.0 kB in 158 objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ ConflatedBroadcastChannel$State.value
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │                                      ~~~~~
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 15.0 kB in 157 objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ MediaControllerCompat.mToken
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │                            ~~~~~~
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$Token instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 13.0 kB in 139 objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ MediaSessionCompat$Token.mExtraBinder
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplApi21$ExtraSession instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 13.0 kB in 137 objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplApi21$ExtraSession.this$0
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │                                                            ~~~~~~
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplApi29 instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 12.4 kB in 136 objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplApi21.mCallback
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │                                               ~~~~~~~~~
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ├─ com.mixhalo.client.service.AudioPlayerService$SessionCallback instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 96 B in 4 objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    this$0 instance of com.mixhalo.client.service.AudioPlayerService
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ AudioPlayerService$SessionCallback.this$0
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: │                                         ~~~~~~
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ╰→ com.mixhalo.client.service.AudioPlayerService instance
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.mixhalo.client.service.AudioPlayerService received
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ​     Service#onDestroy() callback and Service not held by ActivityThread)
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ​     Retaining 10.0 kB in 101 objects
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ​     key = 357606dd-731d-402e-a7f6-adb6ba37aabb
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ​     watchDurationMillis = 6719
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ​     retainedDurationMillis = 1719
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ​     mApplication instance of com.mixhalo.client.App
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ​     mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ====================================
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: 0 LIBRARY LEAKS
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: A Library Leak is a leak caused by a known bug in 3rd party code that you do not have control over.
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: See https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals-how-leakcanary-works/#4-categorizing-leaks
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ====================================
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: 0 UNREACHABLE OBJECTS
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: An unreachable object is still in memory but LeakCanary could not find a strong reference path
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: from GC roots.
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ====================================
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: METADATA
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: Please include this in bug reports and Stack Overflow questions.
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 31
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: Build.MANUFACTURER: Google
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: LeakCanary version: 2.7
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: App process name: com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=1437,misses=110886,hitRate=1%]
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: RandomAccess[bytes=5834063,reads=110886,travel=56164491159,range=31391064,size=38866865]
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: Heap dump reason: user request
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: Analysis duration: 4946 ms
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: Heap dump file path: /storage/emulated/0/Download/leakcanary-com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug/2021-11-30_17-41-24_788.
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: hprof
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: Heap dump timestamp: 1638322892418
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: Heap dump duration: 2263 ms
2021-11-30 17:43:12.697 com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug D/LeakCanary: ====================================
```

The funniest/weirdest part about this leak is that, if I don't reopen the app right away, an crash inevitably happens in the background silently with LeakCanary, but it is only visible through my Crashlytics implementation.  Here's the stack trace of that:

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.mixhalo.mixhaloclient.debug/leakcanary.internal.HeapAnalyzerService
       at android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel(ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:54)
       at android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel(ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:50)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:3333)
       at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2420)
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2409)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2392)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2334)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startService(IActivityManager.java:5971)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at leakcanary.ServiceWatcher$install$4$2.invoke(ServiceWatcher.kt:85)
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
       at $Proxy3.startService()
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1847)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startForegroundService(ContextImpl.java:1823)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startForegroundService(ContextWrapper.java:779)
       at leakcanary.internal.HeapAnalyzerService$Companion.startForegroundService(HeapAnalyzerService.kt:149)
       at leakcanary.internal.HeapAnalyzerService$Companion.runAnalysis(HeapAnalyzerService.kt:141)
       at leakcanary.internal.HeapDumpTrigger.dumpHeap(HeapDumpTrigger.kt:186)
       at leakcanary.internal.HeapDumpTrigger.checkRetainedObjects(HeapDumpTrigger.kt:150)
       at leakcanary.internal.HeapDumpTrigger.access$checkRetainedObjects(HeapDumpTrigger.kt:29)
       at leakcanary.internal.HeapDumpTrigger$scheduleRetainedObjectCheck$1.run(HeapDumpTrigger.kt:334)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```